# Flutter desktop build fails

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

I am facing the problem that I cannot build the application written in Flutter on macOS. I have used the `flutter doctor` to make the whole configuration complete and the result looks like this:

[image]

Next step that I have made was to change the flutter channel to master by:

`flutter channel master && flutter upgrade`

the last thing that I have made was to execute:

`export set ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true`

Now when I try to build the application (flutter run) I receive an error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

EDIT

If this could help I have opened the project in the Intelij and I cannot run it either. I am even not able to select the target device.

[image]

Comment: so is https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuZde.png the output of `flutter run` command only? or you typed `flutter devices` too (notice: `devices` not `device`)? tried `flutter run -v`?

Comment: Yes, it is the output of the `flutter run`. When I run `flutter devices` I receive a list of 2 devices - macOS and chrome.

Comment: tried `flutter run -v`? -v == verbose

Comment: ok, `flutter run -v` helped me. I had the wrong `Mac development` certificate assigned to the project

Comment: now you will discover the power of flutter: the app showing in 2 seconds after typing `flutter run` ;-)

Comment: For this part: "I have opened the project in the Intelij and I cannot run it either. I am even not able to select the target device." see https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/README.md#ides. There's no official desktop support in IntelliJ yet.